# how to use stanford dependencies parser in python

Tags: python, parsing, stanford-nlp

How to use Stanford Dependency parser in NLTK 
I have tired the below code It is not giving any tree structure. Can please guide, I am new to python and NLTK.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    import os
    sentence = "this is a foo bar i want to parse."

    os.popen("echo '"+sentence+"' > ~/stanfordtemp.txt")
    parser_out = os.popen("~/stanford-parser-full-2014-06-16/lexparser.sh ~/stanfordtemp.txt").readlines()

    bracketed_parse = " ".join( [i.strip() for i in parser_out if (len(i.strip()) > 0) == "("] )
    print bracketed_parse

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Output:
Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [1.3 sec].
Parsing file: /home/stanfordtemp.txt
Parsing [sent. 1 len. 10]: this is a foo bar i want to parse .
Parsed file: /home/stanfordtemp.txt [1 sentences].
Parsed 10 words in 1 sentences (18.05 wds/sec; 1.81 sents/sec).
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried one of the python wrappers listed on the [Stanford NLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) page? [Komatsu and Castner](https://bitbucket.org/torotoki/corenlp-python) appear to be up to v3.3 (current version is 3.4).